# Replacing duplicate dataframe rows with the mean value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with some duplicate rows.

I'm trying locate the duplicates in the DEPTH rows and replace them with a single row with the VARIABLE columns just having the mean of whatever values the duplicates are.

```
ID       DEPTH       VARIABLE 1       VARIABLE 2
111      100         X                X
111      101         X                X
111      101         X                X
111      102         X                X
111      103         X                X
222      100         X                X
222      101         X                X
222      102         X                X
222      102         X                X
222      103         X                X
```

I have attempted to use the `groupby` function

```
df_mean = df_sort.groupby('DEPTH').mean()
```

But I keep getting returns like this:

```
DEPTH       VARIABLE 1       VARIABLE 2
1           X                X
2           X                X
3           X                X
...
```

The duplicated rows are removed with the mean, but the DEPTH now starts from 1 instead of its actual value and the VARIABLES are both sorted to ascending order which I don't want

What I need the dupe rows to be replaced with the calculated mean, while maintaining exactly the same format as the previous dataset.

Comment: Use `groupby("DEPTH", sort=False)`

Comment: @Erfan thank you! This works but still drops the ID column, is there a way to keep that?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, ```df_mean = df_sort.groupby(['ID', 'Depth'], sort=False).mean()``` thanks again